# Server Site Mail Not Send

Tags: php, email

I have created Mail Function php with html its Working Localhost and get Email in my gmail account. i have upload my code server Side Its showing error Like this.

```
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini
```

same code Working in Localhost I get Mail Like this

```
 First Name: Thennarasu
Last Name: w
Email: ammuarasu88@gmail.com
Telephone: 08122404484
Comments: werasdasda
```

But its Not Working In Server Site.

Here Is  My code

Contact form.html

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top"">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Send_form_email.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "pixel.thennarasu@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 


?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

How To set My code in server Side also? please any idea about it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like your server does not have an SMTP server running.

Comment: I am Not used in SMTP my Code @light ?

Comment: The `mail()` function talks to an SMTP server under the hood. Although you have not specified anything to do with SMTP in your code, PHP needs to talk to an SMTP server to run.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP mail() function requires a mail server application running in the server that is running the code (in yout case is local).

So, i really recommend you to use a library like PHPMailer to do this, since you can configure the SMTP output server.

If you don't have any idea how to user PHPMailer, check this great tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/phpmailer-ultimate-tutorial/